# How do i assign model values to render forms with values using ngformbuilder?

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I am using form-builder from https://github.com/formio/ngFormBuilder.
In that i don't want to use API references to store and get my forms data, instead i am getting JSON for form structure and values from my database.

The issue is when I render form and assign values which i get from my database, the values are not binded to ng-model for each form components.

The structure for rendering is (as mentioned in reference)

```
<formio form="form"></formio>
```

When i use src attribue (in above formio tag) to get values from API references provided by forms.io then values are binded but i don't want to use database and API references provided by form.io.

Is there any work around for this ?, I tried with setting data in scope variable but that doesn't work.

Using reference: https://github.com/formio/ngFormBuilder

Comment: Have you tried adding `ng-if="form"` to the element, so it will render only when the data is fetched from the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got solution,

Just add submission attribute holding your scope values as shown below:

```
<formio submission="submission" form="form"></formio>
```

And your scope object in controller:

```
$scope.submission = {            
        data: {
            "name": 'Gautam',
            "address": 'India'
        }

    };
```

Refer link : https://help.form.io/developer/info/#formio-events